# How to tear down wcf service after each web service call

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I inherited a working WCF Web Service with one major flaw - the WCF Service consumes memory and does not release unless the service is restarted.  After a half a day of requests hitting the web service, the memory on the server hosting the service climbs to close to 2 gig and is dead in the water.

I'd like to be able to release memory after the web service has received its response but cannot figure out how (WCF is still new to me). Here's what I have.

1. A dll with a service contract like this.

```vb
    <ServiceContract(Name:="CheckOut", Namespace:="http://localhost:8000/MyService/CheckOut")> _
    Public Interface ICheckOut
       <OperationContract()> _
       Function SubmitOrder(ByVal XMLForSubmitOrder As String) As String
       End Function
```

I build a service reference to expose the contract to my web service.

This is my web service method.

```
Private mMyClient As MyClient
...
<WebMethod()> _
<SoapHeader("MyCredentials")> _
Public Function SubmitOrder(ByVal InputXML As String) As String
    If (MyCredentails IsNot Nothing) Then
        SetMyCredential()
        sReturn = mMyClient.SubmitOrder(InputXML)
        mMyClient.Close() 
        mMyClient = Nothing
        Return sReturn 
    End If
    Return "Invalid recipient credentials"
End Function
```

Unfortunately, the Close and Set to Nothing do nothing to affect the memory consumption of the service.

My service exe looks like this.

```
Imports MyDll.WCFWrapper
Public Class WCFService
    Private mMyServiceHost As ServiceModel.ServiceHost
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        mMyServiceHost = New ServiceModel.ServiceHost(GetType(MyService))
        mMyServiceHost.Open()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        If Not IsNothing(mMyServiceHost) Then
            mMyServiceHost.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

These methods are fired off by the Service Manager.  I'd like to be able to invoke something from my web service method to "tear down" the WCF service after I return.  I am not certain if this is the best methodology but I am at a loss as how to manage the memory usage of the WCF service.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

> **Per-Call Services**
>
> Per-call services are the Windows Communication Foundation default
>   instantiation mode. When the service type is configured for per-call
>   activation, a service instance, a common language runtime (CLR)
>   object, exists only while a client call is in progress. Every client
>   request gets a new dedicated service instance. Figure 2 illustrates
>   how this single-call activation works.

Are you properly disposing any resources that you maintain? Perhaps any database connections or streams that need to be closed? It's hard to tell from your code because you haven't discussed what `SubmitOrder` does for `MyClient`. It is entirely possible that the culprit lies within.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes - database connections are closed.  Will check for streams as well.